# Retrieve selected time from TimePicker

Tags: android, database, deprecated, timepicker

I have a database with a table which contains a start time and an end time. The user has to select both through the Android app, and then I would store the two times in my database.

For now, I have 2 TimePicker in my xml file, and I have 2 TimePicker in my java file `TimePicker start_time = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePickerStart);`

I tried to create a Time : `Time start = new Time(start_time.getCurrentHour(), start_time.getCurrentMinute(), 0);` but this method happens to be deprecated. Do you know another way to do it?

My purpose is to send a notification (Toast?) to the user at those times. Do you know how can I link the current time with the time entered by the user?

I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm really lost here :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date` class instead of `Time`.

Even better use `Calendar`. Most methods of `Date` are deprecated.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, 0);
```

Comment: ok but the constructor of Date needs a day, month, etc. and I don't need that... or maybe I can use the method getTimeInMillis() ? Do you know how should I use it?

Comment: what do you mean by clear ? The constructor Date(int, int, int, int, int) is deprecated too..

Comment: Thank you! And in my database, the type Date is ok? Maybe you know how I can link the current time with the time chosen by the user (to send a notification to the user)?

Comment: yes.. you can get milliseconds from calendar and create a `Date(long millis)` object.

Comment: You have to use AlarmManager. Call set method to set the alarm at `start_time`.. search it to know more abt how to handle alarms..